# Modern way to create php website?

Tags: web-development, php, react, vue.js

I am seeking a way to use/incorporate more modern tech to our front end stack at work.

Our pages always follow this flow:

landing -> shipping -> payment -> receipt

they are all php files and getting a product names and such from backend.
for a frontend, it is very old school HTML/CSS( SASS )/jQuery stack.

Another thing to note is that we provide very similar design pages to different clients so parts of the page can be reused. For example, a payment form can be shared between 10 different projects with different color scheme/logo/verbiage. We use `php include` for sharable components for now.

I was wondering if there's any modern alternative to create our pages while meeting these requirements:

- Need to be able to use in .php files
- Light weight since page load speed is one of the most important factor in this industry
- Has to follow the flow shown above
- Can turn into components to be reused in different projects( component library using Vue or React? )

I'd like to go more modern way even if it's an overkill.

Thanks in advance for your advise!

Edit: by "modern tech", I mean something that's being talked about and gaining popularity as of 2019. This includes frameworks, preprocessor and such.

Comment: I love this question (and have made it a favourite), but someone is going to ask you to define "modern" :-/

Comment: @Mawg Thanks! I'll edit my post to include my idea of modern.

Answer (score 1):

## Mustache

Consider [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) it is a templating  system. It allows the back end to emit structured data (such as json), and the front end to convert it to html using a template. There is a little more work in the back-end, middle, but less in the front-end.

## CSS

css can be used for the style, logos, etc. You can have two style sheets, one common, and another from a set (one for each client).

## Conclusion

If done well, you can separate: data storage (Database), data processing (output JSON), document structure (Mustache/HTML), style (CSS), layout (CSS).